# Is it possible to perform an operation on an object in a Hashset without iteration

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration, hashset

If there any way we can call the method of an object inside a Hashset which in itself is a value in a Hashmap without making an iterator or a .forEach(lambda) or in any way going through each object sequentially?

Consider we have a Hashmap like this. `Map<Boolean,Set<Place>> selectedMap`

Consider Place extends JComponent and has a boolean value representing if the user had selected the object with the mouse, the map contains a set with all selected and all unselected objects.

If we for example want to call the `remove`-method of all selected objects, is there a way of doing that in the manner outlined above?

Comment: You always have to iterate over the Set, either implicit or explicit. You can't access it randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a method for **all** the elements in a `Set`, you must iterate over the elements of that `Set`.

That said, instead of an explicit loop, in Java 8 you can use the `forEach` method:

```
selectedMap.get(true).forEach(Place::remove);
```

or

```
selectedMap.get(true).forEach(place -> place.remove(...));
```

in case the `remove()` method requires some arguments.